# Discord.js mute command and create muterole doesn't work and gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a mute command. If a `Muted` role isn't created, I want the bot to autocreate one and overwrite every channel permission so users with the role can't send messages.

**My Code:**

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'mute':
      const person = message.guild.member(
        message.mentions.users.first() && message.guild.members.fetch(args[1])
      );
      if (!person) return message.reply("Couldn't find that member!");
      if (person.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
        return message.reply("You don't have permissions to mute members!");

      const muterole = message.guild.roles.fetch(
        (role) => role.name === 'Muted'
      );

      if (!muterole) {
        muterole = message.guild.roles.create(
          (name = 'Muted'),
          (color = 0x000000),
          Permissions('VIEW_CHANNEL')
        );
        message.channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
      }

      const time = args[2];

      if (!time)
        return message.reply('How many time do you want him to be quiet?');

      person.roles.add(muterole);
      message.channel.send(`@${person.id} has been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`);

      setTimeout(function () {
        person.roles.remove(muterole);
      }, ms(time));
  }
});
```

---

**My Error:**

```js
(node:2780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "<@!402128830472650752>" is not snowflake.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```js
const person = message.guild.member(
  message.mentions.users.first() && message.guild.members.fetch(args[1])
);
```

Use `message.guild.members.cache.get` instead of `message.guild.members.fetch`

Comment: let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() && message.guild.members.get(args[1]))
                                                                                                      ^

TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function

Comment: My bad, `discord.js` v12+ uses `Managers`, so you'll have to use the `cache` property. I edited my answer accordingly 